# How to dlopen a side module larger than 4KB?

Tags: webassembly, emscripten, dlopen

I'm trying to dynamically load a side module from the main module using `dlopen()`.

The side module loads fine as long as its size is smaller than 4KB but I need to load large-size side modules.

Here's a simple code you can test this:

**side.c:**

```
#define SIZE 4000
char dummy[SIZE] = {};

int side(int a)
{
    return SIZE;
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() 
{
    void *handle;
    typedef int (*func_t)(int);

    handle = dlopen("side.wasm", RTLD_NOW);

    if (!handle) {
        printf("failed to open the library\n");
        return 0;
    }
    func_t func = (func_t)dlsym(handle, "side");

    if (!func) {
        printf("failed to find the method\n");
        dlclose(handle);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("side module size: %d byte\n", func(1));
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script async src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**commands:**

```
emcc side.c -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o side.wasm
emcc main.c -s MAIN_MODULE=1 -o main.html --preload-file side.wasm
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

And this is the result I get in the Chrome browser:

> Error in loading dynamic library side.wasm: RangeError: WebAssembly.Compile is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB. Use WebAssembly.compile, or compile on a worker thread.

Can someone please guild me on how to dynamically load a side module larger than 4KB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to do this which uses `loadDynamicLibrary()` and `Asyncify` instead of `dlopen()`.

Here's the full working example code:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EM_JS(void, doLoadLibrary, (), {
    Asyncify.handleAsync(async() => {
    try {
        await loadDynamicLibrary('side.wasm', { loadAsync: true, global: true, nodelete: true, fs: FS });
        console.log('side module size: ' + Module['_side']());
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
    });

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void loadLibrary() {
    printf("before\n");
    doLoadLibrary();
    printf("after\n");
}

int main()
{
}
```

**side.c:**

```
#define SIZE 5000
char dummy[SIZE] = {};

int side(void)
{
    return SIZE;
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="uploadLibrary" type="file" />
  <button id="loadLibrary">loadLibrary</button>
  <script>

    function uploadLibrary() {
      var files = this.files;
      if (files.length === 0) {
        console.log("No file is selected");
        return;
      }
      var file = files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
        Module["FS_createDataFile"]("/", file.name, data, true, true, true);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
    
    function loadLibrary() {
      Module._loadLibrary();
    }

    document.getElementById("uploadLibrary").addEventListener("change", uploadLibrary, false);
    document.getElementById("loadLibrary").addEventListener("click", loadLibrary, false);
  </script>
  <script async src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Makefile:**

```
all: clean
    mkdir -p side
    emcc side.c -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o side/side.wasm
    emcc main.c -s MAIN_MODULE=1 -s ASYNCIFY -s "ASYNCIFY_IMPORTS=['doLoadLibrary']" -s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1 -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['FS']" -o main.html
    python3 -m http.server 8080

clean:
    rm -rf side main.html main.js main.wasm main.data
```

In your browser, click "Choose File" and select the `side/side.wasm` file, and then click "loadLibrary" button.
You will see the following result in the console:

```
before
side module size: 5000
after
```

Comment: But now you are calling your `side()` function indirectly from JS, not from C as you were in the original code-- right? If so, this isn't a full solution as in many cases that may not be feasible or desirable (even putting aside the code refactoring required), especially if data will be shared between the indirect function and the calling module.